# Need help executing binary file on bash terminal with -wall -pedantic -ansi flags

Tags: c, bash, terminal, visual-studio-code, windows-10

Cannot execute program on Visual Studio Code terminal on Windows with -Wall -pedantic -ansi flags. The program for assignment right now is just a simple "Hello World" main in C with a struct

I've tried using the flags on different folder and they work fine on VS Code, but not on the file path I want.

```
gcc -Wall -pednatic -ansi -o q1 -c Question1.c
```

Is what I do on Visual Studio Code terminal in the folder `.../Assignment_1$`

```
-bash: ./q1: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

is what is says when I do `./q1`

Comment: You would most likely have a path issue. You should supply more information for an answer to be generated

Comment: The `-ansi` flag is obsolete these days.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The ANSI C dialect may be obsolete, but the compiler switch is not.

Answer (score 8):

The option `-c` tells GCC to generate an *object* file, not an executable file. Don't use the `-c` option to generate executable (program) files.

Comment: Good catch! I didn't even see the `-c`